# How to stop processing if JSON is too large

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I want to be able to stop processing a request if the JSON that is posted to my controller's action is too large.

The size limit will vary so I don't want to hard code this value in my web.config

Is there a way to check in my controllers action?   Say my limit is 100kb, if it goes over I don't want to waste the servers CPU, I just want to halt and return right away.

Comment: I don't think so, unfortunately. The problem is that there's no way of knowing how large the JSON representation will need to be until it's been created.

Comment: Agree with @ChrisPratt, along with this minified JSON will occupy less space to be stored, compared to human-readable one. You might want to limit the execution before converting it JSON. For example, if you render a list of items, you might want to limit the number of items (with paging or so on). Just before the convertion to JSON and sending it to the browser.

Answer (score 3):

There is such a setting for this in the Json class (See Code Below):

```
var jsonResult = Json(jsonString, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
jsonResult.maxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
return jsonResult;
```

It can also be done in configuration like this (Web.config):

```
<configuration> 
  <system.web.extensions>
   <scripting>
       <webServices>
           <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
       </webServices>
   </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```